# After compiz configuration edited

Tags: compiz

I edit compiz configuration with ccsm and after that my ubuntu will go to must os!
when i open tabs in chrome or firefox them use many usage of cpu and cpu fan start to work hardly!
i delete these files from my home folder but doesn't effect!

```
sudo rm -rf .compiz-1 .gconf .gnome2 .gnome
```

how can i restart compiz effects and bring ubuntu before compiz changes?

Here is the output of *top*:

[image]

Comment: try `unity --reset` from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Open ccsm and go to "Preferences" then select "Reset to defaults".

[image]

Comment: I do this but my cpu usage doesn't decrease! when i use firefox or chrome and switch between tabs cpu usage increase! help me to fix this problem.

Comment: can you check your computer cpu usage with firefox and chrome?

Comment: Of course. Check it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/cpu.firefox.chromium.jpg Although I have a very powerful computer, the cpu usage isn't so low...